# Integration limits at points where denominator is zero

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If the domintator of some function $f$ from $[a,b]$ to $ℝ^2$, be equal to zero at some point $c∈[a,b]$, does it necessarily imply that the function is not integrable on $[a,b]$? If yes, how should the limits of the definite integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$ be justified with regard to the point $c$?

Note: I'm not talking about those examples where $f$ can be simplified such that the denominator of $f(c)$  is no longer zero.

Comment: There are some standard examples mentioned in calculus books, for example $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx$ which as an improper Riemann integral is defined as $\lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_a^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the counterexample $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \; dx =\pi$, where at $x=0$ the denominator is a non-removable zero.  The integral of a function with a denominator that equals zero may be integratable.  You can split the improper integral into two integrals and then use means of integration to calculate them separately:

$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \; dx + \displaystyle\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \; dx$

Comment: Does that mean $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \; dx$ is meaningless?

Comment: What do you mean by "meaningless"?

Comment: I mean you can not take the defintite integral when your function at some point is undefined. I think what you calculated in the last line is the integral of $f(x)=\frac{sinx}{x}$ when for example at x=0, f(x) is zero and at any other point is equal to$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ . Without this expanding of $f$,$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \; dx$ is meaningless I suppose

Comment: This is not a particularly useful example because $\sin(x)/x$ is actually a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and can be continuously extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$. It's not "algebraically simplifiable" to be sure but the singularity is still removable in the analytic sense of the word "removable".

Comment: You can calculate the definite integral when a point is undefined though, this comes up often in complex analysis.  I was showing to use limits for the improper integral but you don't have to split the integral up.