# How can I calculate this integral considering the point where denominator is zero?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_{0}^{3}\frac{1}{(y-1)^\frac{2}{3}}dy$$

If I substitute $u=y-1$ and split this integral up and calculate it for $0≤y<1$ and $1<y≤3$ then I get the anwer $I=3(2^\frac{1}{3}+1)$. But then how about the integration on the point $y=1$? Is my approach correct?

Can someone write the correct process of integration of $I$ for me wherein denominator being $0$ at $y=1$ is also considered?

Comment: The integral cannot be calculated at 1. The approach you have followed is correct though

Comment: @sai-kartik So when it can not be defined at 1 is it correct to write the limits of the integral from 0 to 3?

Comment: We can write , but it would be a sin to place the limits directly after evaluating the integral

Comment: @sai-kartik After evaluating integral we have numbers not limits, don't we? I dont understand in which step can this sin occur

Comment: What I meant was: evaluating the integral (without splitting) and then just placing in 3 and 0 for the limits. **That** would be a sin

Comment: @sai-kartik can you please answer my comment under Alvin's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand is unbounded at $y=1$. Thus we have an improper integral
$$I = \int _0^1 \frac{1}{(y-1)^{2/3}} dy + \int _1^3 \frac{1}{(y-1)^{2/3}}dy =: I_1+I_2. $$
The improper integral $I_1$ is computed as
$$ I_1 = \lim _{t\to 1-} \int _{0}^t \frac{1}{(y-1)^{2/3}}d(y-1) = \lim _{t\to 1-} 3(y-1)^{1/3}\Big\vert _0^t = 3. $$
$I_2$ is computed similarly.

---

If at least one of the $I_i$ is unbounded, then the initial improper integral diverges. Otherwise converges and its value is $I_1+I_2$.

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it..

Comment: @Alvin Lepik so when ,as you wrote in last lines, $I_1$ APPROACHES 3, then why do we not see any sign of this APPROACHING in the final answer? I mean finally we write the answer IS 3(2^(1/3)+1) not that the answer APPROACHES  3(2^(1/3)+1). Why?

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh That's a valid objection. It is a limit and its value is fixed. Apologies for confusing notation.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh Yes you're right the answer will be tending to something. It cannot be exact.

Comment: @sai-kartik how about now that he has edited. I think now it is exact. because the limit's value is fixed on 3.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh doesn't limit mean a "tending -to" quantity? You cannot have an **exact** answer. only a very good estimate(limit)

Comment: @sai-kartik yes that's right, the answer approaches 3 when t approaches 1-. But I mean the limit value is exact, which means the value to which the answer is approaching doesnt change while t is approahing 1-.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh yep.I agree.

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be written as:
$$\lim_\limits{b\to1^-}\int_0^b\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{(1-y)^{\frac23}}+\lim_\limits{c\to 1^+}\int_c^3\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{(1-y)^{\frac23}}$$

Comment: I read somewhere that for some functions, integral at points where the function is not defined, can be calculated using "complex planes". I dont have any idea of how that is possible. But does that relate to doing sin?? Does it condradict you? see the comments on the answer of this link. Im really confused about how such sin can be done.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3694018/integration-limits-at-points-where-denominator-is-zero

Comment: I speak only for the real part of things. I have not much knowledge on complex analysis. You could probably do in complex plane without committing that sin.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh no problem :)